# D3 Tooltip not Working

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

Below is my code to load a D3 multine chart in a leaflet map popup everything works fine but i am not able to load tooltips the mouse events are not picking up. Even console.log on mousemove over the element is not working also i am able to inspect the element on right click. I also do not see anything related to this element in event listners.

```
  var chartdiv = document.createElement("div");
  chartdiv.className = "pricechart";
  // set the dimensions and margins of the graph
  var margin = {top: 25, right: 70, bottom: 80, left: 50},
      width = 480 - margin.left - margin.right,
      height = 240 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
  // parse the date / time
  //var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%Y-%m-%d");
  // set the ranges
  var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
  var yrain = d3.scaleLinear().range([height, 0]);
  // define the line
  var smi_line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.smi); })

  var rain_line = d3.line()
      .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
      .y(function(d) { return y(d.rain); });

  // gridlines in x axis function
  function make_x_gridlines() {
      return d3.axisBottom(x)
  }
  // gridlines in y axis function
  function make_y_gridlines() {
      return d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5)
  }
  // append the svg obgect to the body of the page
  // appends a 'group' element to 'svg'
  // moves the 'group' element to the top left margin
  var svg = d3.select(chartdiv).append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  // Scale the range of the data
  x.domain(d3.extent(stats, function(d) { return d.date; }));
  y.domain([d3.min(stats, function(d) { return Math.min(d.smi, d.rain, 0); }) , d3.max(stats, function(d) { return Math.max(d.smi, d.rain, 100); })]);

  svg.append("linearGradient")
        .attr("id", "temperature-gradient")
        .attr("gradientUnits", "userSpaceOnUse")
        .attr("x1", 0).attr("y1", y(0))
        .attr("x2", 0).attr("y2", y(100))
      .selectAll("stop")
        .data([
          {offset: "0%", color: "rgb(252, 0, 23)"},
          {offset: "25%", color: "rgb(252, 0, 23)"},
          {offset: "26%", color: "rgb(255, 254, 52)"},
          {offset: "50%", color: "rgb(255, 254, 52)"},
          {offset: "51%", color: "rgb(44, 255, 254)"},
          {offset: "75%", color: "rgb(44, 255, 254)"},
          {offset: "76%", color: "rgb(4, 20, 251)"},
          {offset: "100%", color: "rgb(4, 20, 251)"}
        ])
      .enter().append("stop")
        .attr("offset", function(d) { return d.offset; })
        .attr("stop-color", function(d) { return d.color; });

  // add the X gridlines
  svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "grid")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(make_x_gridlines()
         .tickSize(-height)
         .tickFormat("")
     )

  // add the Y gridlines
  svg.append("g")
     .attr("class", "grid")
     .call(make_y_gridlines()
         .tickSize(-width)
         .tickFormat("")
     )

  // Add the SMI path.
  svg.append("path")
     .data([stats])
     .attr("class", "smi-line")
     //.style("stroke", "#ff0000")
     .attr("d", smi_line);

 // Add the Rain path.
 svg.append("path")
    .data([stats])
    .attr("class", "rain-line")
    //.style("stroke", "#ff0000")
    .attr("d", rain_line);

  // Add the X Axis
  svg.append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
     .call(d3.axisBottom(x)
              .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat("%d-%b-%y")))
     .selectAll("text")
     .style("text-anchor", "end")
     .attr("dx", "-.8em")
     .attr("dy", ".15em")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-45)");

  // text label for the x axis
  svg.append("text")
     .attr("transform",
           "translate(" + (width/2) + " ," +
                          (height + margin.bottom -30) + ")")
     .style("text-anchor", "middle")
     .attr("dy", "1em")
     .text("Date");

  // Add the Y Axis
  svg.append("g")
     .call(d3.axisLeft(y).ticks(5));

 // text label for the y axis
 svg.append("text")
     .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
     .attr("y", 0 - margin.left)
     .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
     .attr("dy", "1em")
     .style("text-anchor", "middle")
     .text("Soil Moisture Index");

 // Add the Right Y Axis
 svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width + " ,0)")
    .call(d3.axisRight(y).ticks(5)
            .tickFormat(d => (d + " mm")));

// text label for the y axis
svg.append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", width + margin.right -15)
    .attr("x",0 - (height / 2))
    .attr("dy", "1em")
    .style("text-anchor", "middle")
    .text("Rainfall");


    var g = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    var focus = g.append("g")
    .attr("class", "focus")
    .style("display", "none");

    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "x-hover-line hover-line")
        .attr("y1", 0)
        .attr("y2", height);
    focus.append("line")
        .attr("class", "y-hover-line hover-line")
        .attr("x1", width)
        .attr("x2", width);
    focus.append("circle")
        .attr("r", 7.5);
    focus.append("text")
        .attr("x", 15)
        .attr("dy", ".31em");
    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .attr("class", "overlay")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .on("mouseover", function() { focus.style("display", null); })
        .on("mouseout", function() { focus.style("display", "none"); })
        .on("mousemove", mousemove);

    var bisectDate = d3.bisector(function(d) { return d.year; }).left;
    function mousemove() {
      console.log('mousemove');
      var x0 = x.invert(d3.mouse(this)[0]),
          i = bisectDate(data, x0, 1),
          d0 = data[i - 1],
          d1 = data[i],
          d = x0 - d0.year > d1.year - x0 ? d1 : d0;
      focus.attr("transform", "translate(" + x(d.year) + "," + y(d.value) + ")");
      focus.select("text").text(function() { return d.value; });
      focus.select(".x-hover-line").attr("y2", height - y(d.value));
      focus.select(".y-hover-line").attr("x2", width + width);
    }
```

Comment: Could you give us a snippet of your `stats` data? Also why is your `parseTime` variable commented out?

Comment: Does the rect with the mouseover have a css fill style of none?